# Highstocks peak value not showing without zooming

Tags: highcharts

I've got one value at 12 in a serie almost always between 0 and 5, on a datetime yAxis.
The max is set to this value programmatically. 
But without zooming in, you dont see any peak in the line. Tooltip doesn't show this value neither.

The problem is why would a user zoom in, (here or there ?) , as he wont see any peaking tip on the line. (I found the value with the navigator because I knew it should be there.)

Moreover, I end up with a very tiny line of 5 pixels (as my other values are very small), jammed at the bottom of the chart, and a lot of air above until 12 the max ! 
Any idea welcome.

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo, on the jsFiddle.net

Comment: Well, it's not allowed, nor possible.  I've tried to post picture, with no luck...

Comment: Well without any exmaple how we can replicate your issue?

Comment: It's not an issue, in fact: it's the normal behavior of the chart I imagine : doesnt show all values without zooming in...

Comment: Indeed, it is realted with the fact that highstock uses a [datagrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping), which group points. You can disable it by paraemer.