# Highstock Not showing max data value without Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

My question is same as addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932284/highstocks-peak-value-not-showing-without-zooming), I am not able to add comment to that question.
Highstock is Not able to show max data point without zoom.
Here in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YB6zv/1/). I am getting data values of y-axis between 0 t0 1.7, but am getting max value is 3.19(See in Fiddle April 9 22:53), it is not showing. when we click on the Month zoom button then only it is showing. If we click on All,6M,3M it is not showing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var seriesOptions = [];
    var xaAxisData=[];

    var yAxisData=[]; 

for (var i=0; i<xaAxisData.length && i<yAxisData.length; i++){
    seriesOptions.push([xaAxisData[i],yAxisData[i]]);
       }
    // Create the chart
    var chart =new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
               renderTo: "container",
               height: 500,
               zoomType: 'x'
           },
        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1,
            inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 280
        },
        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        credits: {
              enabled: false
          },
        xAxis: {
                title: {
                   text: 'Time'
               },
               type: 'datetime',
               },
               yAxis: {
                   title: {
                       text: "Stock "
                   },
                   lineWidth: 1,
                   min:0,
                   gridLineWidth: 0,
                   endOnTick : false,
                   max:5

               },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            showInLegend: true,
            data : seriesOptions,
            lineWidth : 1,
            marker : {
                enabled : true,
                radius : 2
            }
        }]
    });
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `dataGrouping`. When zoomed far out it no longer shows **all** the points, but rather each "point" is a combination of several points, and are shown as a average.

This is because these are (two of) the default opptions for `dataGrouping`:

```
dataGrouping: {
    enabled: true,
    approximation: 'average'
}
```

You could do `enabled: false` ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YB6zv/2/)), but you might find that this dramatically slows down your chart, depending on the data size.

If you are really keen on seeing the "top" points you could to `approximation: 'high'` ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YB6zv/3/)), which would show the highest value within each grouping.

There are several other options that can be viewed under the [dataGrouping API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping). It comes down to how you want it to look and perform, and how much it should reflect the actual values.

Comment: Thanks Ondkloss, That's perfect Answer..!

Comment: If we have negative value, its not working. Here In[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YB6zv/4/)

Comment: What (and when) is your lowest value? Also, then you want to show the lowest point, or the highest point?

Comment: You have to define what you want to show if many points with varying values are close to eachother. What  if [-100,100,0] is next to eachother. What would you like to show then, if using dataGrouping? If you want to show the exacts (all three values) you will have to disable dataGrouping.

Comment: Thank You very much, I want to show all data points without hiding any value,I disabled dataGrouping. here in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YB6zv/6/)

Comment: Glad it worked out! Just remember that this will be very hard for your chart if you get a lot of data.